# remove some characters from a string in python3 with translate function

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, interactive

remove some characters from a string in python3 with translate function

```
name=G30ffr3Y
name.translate(None,"0123")
>>GffrY
```

but when i try it with python3 its not working I tried with name.replcae()its not working fine

Comment: and what you get ?

Comment: in python3 name.translate() function has only one argument